# I need help making a website crawler using php

Tags: php, web-crawler

I really want to make a website crawler that goes to a website, scans it for links, puts the links in a database and moves on to another website. I found one website but the code was really buggy. If you have seen anything like this or have written one your self.

Comment: How many sites are you wanting to crawl?  Unless you are spawning multiple PHP processes on the server, you are going to have trouble.  PHP is single-threaded, and you won't be efficiently crawling pages.

Comment: `please post the code, not the website!` I highly discourage/disagree with that, the website will be of much greater use then pre-cooked code, also for future reference.

Comment: is there any other language that is more efficient? I just want a web crawler

Comment: You'll find more readymade crawlers in the Perl area. WWW::Mechanize comes to mind.

Comment: i dont really know perl so if possible make it in php/python/js

Comment: a gui for mac would also work

Comment: Begging won't get you anywhere, have some dignity.

Comment: You should read this similar item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733599/is-there-a-list-of-known-web-crawlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one, so if anyone is looking, here is the link: [php-crawler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-crawler/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't find anything suitable for PHP, as it is generally for short-running pages. Many severs, for example, are set to time out at 30 seconds. You can write PHP for command-line scripts, but I suspect that's not what you want.

Anywyay, if you want a pre-packaged solution, why care about the language?

I would recommend something like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to crawl the sites and save them to disc. Then you can iterate over the files and directories, and pull out links. The hard bit is crawling the sites (it's not simple). You can write the code to pull out links without too much difficulty.